# How to display y-axis position within a div?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've a Selenium question.

I've tried, body y-axis position : `driver.execute_script('return window.pageYOffset')`

How to display y-axis position within a div?

Answer (score 0):

To display the `x-axis` and `y-axis` position of any [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) e.g. the *Search Box* within [Google Home Page](https://www.google.com/) you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
  print(element.location)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  {'x': 439, 'y': 184}
  ```

---

To print only the *`y-axis`* you can use:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
  location = element.location
  x, y = location['x'], location['y']
  print(y)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  184
  ```